# Serial.available() function for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to implement a function in another micro-controller which works like `serial.available()`. I don't know how it works. I read about `Serial.available()` in [this link](https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/available).

Whenever I write a string on the terminal, it prints the length of the string. Can anyone tell me how it works?

Answer (score 2):

It reports the difference between the head and the tail of the circular buffer the incoming characters are stored in.

The way serial reception on the Arduino works is:

1. A character is received into the internal hardware RX buffer (`UDRx`)
2. An interrupt is triggered
3. An interrupt service routine (ISR) is executed
4. The character in `UDRx` is read and, if there is room, stored in a circular buffer (`_rx_buffer`).
5. The `head` pointer of `_rx_buffer` is incremented and wrapped if needed.

When you actually read a character with `Serial.read()` the following happens:

1. If the `head` and `tail` of `rx_buffer` are equal, return `-1`
2. Get the character at `tail` from `_rx_buffer`
3. Increment `tail` and wrap if needed
4. Return the character

So when you use `Serial.available()` it just returns `head - tail` (taking into account the wrapping, so the sum is slightly more complex than a simple subtraction).

You should examine the files `HardwareSerial.h` and `HardwareSerial.cpp` in the Ardino AVR core software.

Comment: i understand till step3

Comment: Step three in which block?

Comment: The character in UDRx is read and, if there is room, stored in a circular buffer (_rx_buffer).

Comment: first block....

Comment: You should read the ATMega328P datasheet - the section about the USART.

Comment: @Beginner: Everything should be obvious once you understand what a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) is.